# Sequelize connection error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to transfer my application to a new machine. It works on the old machine perfectly, and I have been trying to copy the settings as closely as possible, but there is something missing. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake._callback (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboard-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:63:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboard-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboard-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:393:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboard-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:392:13
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the node-mysql package, did you try re-downloading the packages?

Comment: Why don't you try to increment the value of `acquireTimeout` of the connection?

Comment: Im still trying to find a definitive cause, but as a side-note node `4.2.0` was released under 12 hours ago, very possible that may be the culprit.

Comment: @JonathanS. - Thanks for that suggestion - I tried updating the associated packages, to no avail :( As for the `acquireTimeout`, I thought about doing that, but the only reason I haven't is because I'm not using pooling, and it's working as is on the other machine. @Aren - that's a good point, maybe I'll try rolling back to a previous version of NodeJS to see if it resolves the issue - I'll post my results soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just confirmed the problem is either Sequelize / mysql in conjunction with **Node 4.2.0** after manually re-installing 4.1.1 my problems went away.

Downgrade to **Node 4.1.x** or wait for a patch/fix/etc to solve your issues.

### Additional Information

The bug has been reported [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1236) on the `node-mysql` repository issue tracker. Seems someone regressed something in Node 4.2.0 and it wasn't caught. [Here's](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/3331) the pull request to fix it which was merged in and is in the candidate for 4.2.1.

### Update Oct 13th, 2015

Node 4.2.1 was just released ([Changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.2.1/CHANGELOG.md)) containing the aforementioned fix. Upgrading to **4.2.1** should also fix your problems.

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much for your help - saved me a lot of headache! I downgraded to 4.1.1 and my application booted right up!

Comment: See [This Pull Request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/3337) It looks like they're rushing out 4.2.1 today or tomorrow because there's 2 regressions that are breaking things everywhere.

Comment: @Jonathan You can now safely update to the latest node version **4.2.1** if you wish.

Comment: Thank you - I'll check it out tomorrow!